# Excel Countifs formula with one color criteria and the rest normal

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I get an excel 2010 formula that can do countifs criteria that includes color? I saw this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2815384  but it only gives me the count of cells with that color. I need an additional criteria to be available in the formula or I need the VBA that is provided in the link there to only work on visible cells (using filters on my data). Any ideas? I appreciate the help.

Here is the code provided by the link:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
    Dim datax As range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Comment: I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Weatherly's answer is just about what you're looking for.

The only thing I had issues with when running his code is this line:

`if datax.Hidden = false`

This becomes `datax.EntireRow.Hidden = False` and that seems to fix things.

It also doesn't like to update when it should.

In doing some poking around, I added `Application.Volatile`, but it doesn't seem to update when the color changes or when the filter changes.

I was forced to add a Worksheet SelectionChange event that finally got it updating when it was supposed to (probably too often).

Excel doesn't have a "color change" event, so the best we can do is update when the selection changes (short of adding a timer that runs Application.Calculate, but that sounds like more effort than it's worth).

The final code:

```
Function CountColors(TheRange As Range, TheColor As Range) As Long
Application.Volatile
Dim c, color, cellcount
color = TheColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each c In TheRange
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = False And c.Interior.ColorIndex = color Then cellcount = cellcount + 1
Next c
CountColors = cellcount
End Function
```

Sheet1 Event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

The first piece of code goes in a module (Module1 is the default).

The second piece of code goes in your worksheet object (Sheet1 (Sheet1) in my example).

[image: CountColors]

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm so far. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So is your issue that you don't want filtered data to be found when you apply the custom function?  Because if so, the following should fix it:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
    Dim datax As range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor And datax.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, as a suggestion so as not to affect your reputation score you should place comments using the "add a comment" under the original question rather than in the form at the bottom. This response will be flagged as not useful as it is not an actual answer. Hope this helps you in the future.

Comment: I tried to add a comment at first, but it wouldn't let me because I don't have 50 reputation lol

Comment: Lol, or maybe I should have given you a little more time :). Regards

Comment: When I use the version from @AndrewWeatherly as is up there, I get the output "#VALUE!"

Perhaps I'm not doing it the same way? I enter a range, and then select a cell for criteria right? (Range of cells, Criteria Cell)

Comment: @AndrewWeatherly
My data set:
Column A has either "Active" or "Non-Active" as it's value.
Column B has text in cells, but these cells are color coded.

I am able to use the one that microsoft uses to just tell me the counts for colors of cells, however, when I filter on Column A so that only "Active" members show, the count remains the same.

Comment: @user1274820 Can you post what the VBA would look like if I were to do the replacements like you mention? I'm a bit new to the VBA world and don't have this down quite yet.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user4584837 Change `datax.Hidden = False` to `datax.EntireRow.Hidden = False` and add `Application.Volatile` to the top of the function. It should work as intended.

Comment: You might also want to add `Application.Calculate` to the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event since it doesn't like to update it when it should.

Comment: The users above are correct. You want the datax.EntireRow.Hidden = False