# Dynamically build multiple criteria for Excel COUNTIFS using yes/no list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a COUNTIF into a COUNTIFS where the criteria would be a dynamic range made by typing a "y" for yes in col A next to a student misbehavior in col B.

[image: list of example misbehaviors]

Teachers would log student misbehaviors using data validation lists in a student information sheet. In the student info sheet (sheet14 in this example), note that the odd rows pertain to the misbehaviors, and the even rows pertain to missing assignments. We want Excel to only tally the misbehavior info if a student reaches 5 of any misbehaviors marked as "y" in the sheet named Lookups. And, we want Excel to overlook any cell that is already filled with yellow color.

I can make this work by typing literal OR criteria, such as "locker" in the code below, but I can't figure out how to make this work using the yes/no list on the other sheet. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks so much!

```
    Sub Q1_Email_Student_Info()
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim cell As Range, studentCell As Range
    Dim ci As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range, ce As Range
    Dim sTo As String
    Set emailRng = Worksheets("EmailRecipients").Range("B1:B10")
    Dim emailyesno As Range
    Set emailyesno = Worksheets("EmailRecipients").Range("A1:A10")
    sTo = ""
    Dim misbehaveyesno As Range
    Set misbehaveyesno = Worksheets("Lookups").Range("A1:A10")
    sBad = ""
    
    For Each cell In emailyesno.Cells
        If (LCase(cell.Value) = "y") Then
            sTo = sTo & ";" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cell

    '**TRYING TO USE SOMETHING LIKE THIS FOR THE COUNTIFS BELOW
    For Each cell In misbehaveyesno.Cells
        If (LCase(cell.Value) = "y") Then
            sBad = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       
    str = "5th Grade Students - " & Date & vbCr
    
    For Each cell In Sheet14.Range("C4:ZZ100").Cells
        ci = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
        If Not (ci = 6) And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        '****************************************************************************
            Set studentCell = Sheet14.Cells(cell.Row, "A")
            
            With cell
                If cell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Missing: " & .CommentThreaded.Text & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                    ElseIf Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Missing: " & .Comment.Text & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                    Else
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                    End If
                Else

    '**TRYING TO CONVERT THIS COUNTIF INTO A COUNTIFS WITH CRITERIA THAT ARE TOGGLED ON IN THE LOOKUPS SHEET.
    '**TRYING TO USE MULTIPLE BEHAVIOR CRITERIA ONLY MARKED "Y" ON THE LOOKUPS SHEET
    '**IF THERE ARE 5 OR MORE INSTANCES OF CRITERIA MARKED "Y" AND COLORED NOT YELLOW, THEN COUNT AND INCLUDE THEM.

                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(cell.EntireRow, "locker") >= 5 Then
                        If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                            str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Behavior: " & CStr(.Value) & " (Staff: " & .CommentThreaded.Text & ")" & vbCr
                        ElseIf Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                            str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Behavior: " & CStr(.Value) & " (Staff: " & .Comment.Text & ")" & vbCr
                        Else
                            str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Behavior: " & CStr(.Value) & vbCr
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        '****************************************************************************
        End If
    Next cell
    
    str = str & vbCr & "6th Grade Students - " & Date & vbCr
    
    For Each cell In Sheet4.Range("C4:ZZ100").Cells
        ci = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
        If Not (ci = 6) And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        '****************************************************************************
            Set studentCell = Sheet4.Cells(cell.Row, "A")
            
            With cell
                If cell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Missing: " & .CommentThreaded.Text & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                    ElseIf Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Missing: " & .Comment.Text & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                    Else
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                    End If
                Else
                    If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Behavior: " & CStr(.Value) & " (Staff: " & .CommentThreaded.Text & ")" & vbCr
                    ElseIf Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Behavior: " & CStr(.Value) & " (Staff: " & .Comment.Text & ")" & vbCr
                    Else
                        str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Behavior: " & CStr(.Value) & vbCr
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        '****************************************************************************
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = sTo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Daily Behavior and Missing Work Report, " & Date & ", Q1"
        
        '****************************************************************************
        Dim wdDoc As Object
        Dim olinsp As Object
        
        Set wdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
        Set olinsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olinsp.WordEditor
        
        If Not IsEmpty(str) Then
            wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore str
        Else
            MsgBox prompt:="No cells meet the criteria"
            GoTo SafeExit
        End If
        '****************************************************************************
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set olinsp = Nothing
    str = Empty
    
SafeExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error'" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
    
End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Call ThisWorkbook.Check_Outlook

    With Target
       Select Case .Address
          Case "$A$1":
          Call Q1_Email_Student_Info
      End Select
   End With

   Cancel = True
End Sub
```

[image: example of student information sheet]

========================REVISED 7/2============================
I found a workaround after studying a number of other posts. I still haven't figured out how to build in a "YES/NO" list on another sheet to add/remove misbehaviors.

The post I mainly used was [Excel Countifs formula with one color criteria and the rest normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328071/excel-countifs-formula-with-one-color-criteria-and-the-rest-normal). Here is how I modified it...

In each worksheet's code, I inserted this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

I also changed the code that I previously posted (see below for revisions). Note that I've also added a column A, shifting the list of student names to col B (for something that I'm planning on next). Also, I added a new column D to contain the values of the COUNTIF(), which are auto-updated on the worksheet_selectionchange. I'm using these values (if >= 5) to include a misbehavior reminder for teachers in the email.

```
For Each cell In Sheet3.Range("C4:ZZ100").Cells
    ci = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
    If Not (ci = 6) And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
    '****************************************************************************
        Set studentCell = Sheet3.Cells(cell.Row, "A")
        With cell
            If cell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
                If Not .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
                    str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Missing: " & .CommentThreaded.Text & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                ElseIf Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                    str = str & studentCell.Value & " - Missing: " & .Comment.Text & " (Staff: " & CStr(.Value) & ")" & vbCr
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next cell

For Each cell In Sheet3.Range("C4:C100").Cells
    Set studentCell = Sheet3.Cells(cell.Row, "A")
    Set countCell = Sheet3.Cells(cell.Row, "C")
        If countCell.Value >= 5 Then
            str = str & vbCr & studentCell.Value & " - End of line today due to " & CStr(countCell.Value) & " locker trips."
        End If
Next cell
```

I am not very experienced with Excel VBA, so I'm sure I'm missing ways to refactor this.

In Module 1, I inserted the following code. It will overlook any cells that are filled yellow, which is the color that shows us teachers that we've already dealt with a student's behaviors.

```
Function CountColors(TheRange As Range, TheColor As Range) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Dim c As Range
    Dim color As Long
    Dim cellcount As Long
    color = TheColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each c In TheRange
        If c.Value = "locker" And c.Interior.ColorIndex = color Then
            cellcount = cellcount + 1
        End If
    Next
    CountColors = cellcount
End Function
```

Lastly, in the odd cells of column D, I entered the CountColors() function: =CountColors(E5:BA5,C5). It's working for now, but it'd be great to be able to somehow automate it with a Y/N toggle rather than having to type a Boolean OR in the CountColors function. Thanks again.

[image: image of example spreadsheet]

Comment: So you have code to input the value to "Late Assignments & Misbehaviours", then you're counting instances on that sheet?  If that is not the case, then how would you see multiple "Y" for the same offense for the image you have listed first.  To count unique values, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676068/count-unique-values-in-excel

Comment: Thanks Cyril for your response and link. I really appreciate it. I'll study your solution. Different teachers can open the sheet and input data, and I was just trying to figure out a way to tally and flag a grouping of any 5 "misbehaviors" that were marked with a "y" on the other sheet. This may change to 3 or 4 or 10 instances depending on our needs, but I was just searching for a more automated way of doing this, and didn't know if it was possible with COUNTIF or COUNTIFS. Typically, us teachers look at the sheet and export the data on a daily basis. Thanks again.